# database size limit in SQL Server 2012 Express Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to use SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. Does someone know the maximum file size limitation of the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Express version database size limit is 10GB.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)